# Need assistance with script task component: Am getting Index outbounds of the array

Tags: ssis

I am currently creating a SSIS program that reads data from a file, does some processing with that data, and outputs it to a OLE DB Destination task. However, everytime I run my application, I keep getting this error: "An error occurred: Index was outside the bounds of the array".I have changed my code many of times within the script task, but I still seem to be getting this error. Does anyone have any idea on what could be the problem? If so, any hints and suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

This is my code within script task..

```
 bool found=false;



   try
     {

         while (Row.NextRow())
         {
             int Rows = 0;
             int length = 0;
            //int length = Row.Source.Length;


             foreach (char c in Row.Source)
             {
                 length++;
                 Console.Write(length);


             }


             while (found == false || length==0)
             {

                 char c = Row.Source[Rows];
                 Rows++;
                 if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c))
                 {


                     length = length - 1;
                 }

                 else
                 {



                     while (length != 0)
                     {

                         Rows++;


                         if (Row.Source[Rows] != ' ')
                         {
                             Row.Source01 = Row.Source.Replace(Row.Source[Rows], ' ');

                         }
                         length = length - 1;
                     }
                     found = true;



                 }
             }
             found = false;
         }
     }

     catch (Exception e)
     {
         bool pbCancel = false;
         this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "myScriptComponent", "An error occurred: " + e.Message, "", 0, out pbCancel);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will post it tommorow as I dont have within my possession at the moment...

Comment: That's not all of your code though. At a minimum, there's no declaration for your Row data type. Bigger picture, logically, what are you doing? Yes, you're doing file work and pushing rows onto the buffer. Something in there about checking for whitespace and other bits where you check each character but I'm not seeing the whole.

Comment: That's is due to the data being handled. Not knowing what the data is and on what line it breaks makes it hard to help you. Let's start off with you placing a breakpoint and step trough the code to see at what point it throws the error.